# JavaPoet check if TypeName is instance of List

Tags: java, javapoet

In JavaPoet I can get a TypeName from every Class like this as an example for the `List` class.

```
TypeName TYPE_LIST = ClassName.get(List.class);
```

But how can I check now if a given `TypeName` is an instance of a List?  Let's say I have a method which returns a `List<String>`. I can get the return type by using:

```
TypeName returnTyoe = TypeName.get(method.getReturnType());
```

How can I check if tis method reurns a `List`? I do not care if it is a `List<String>` I only want to know if it is at least a `List` and ignore the generic parameter completely.

Comment: You could always use `Class.forName`.

Comment: How would this help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an even better way. For everyone also struggling with that use below code:

```
TypeName TYPE_LIST = ClassName.get(List.class);
boolean isList = isFromType(type, TYPE_LIST)

public static boolean isFromType(TypeName requestType, TypeName expectedType) {
    if(requestType instanceof ParameterizedTypeName) {
        TypeName typeName = ((ParameterizedTypeName) requestType).rawType;
        return (typeName.equals(expectedType));
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how is this a **better way**?

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed out correctly, you won't be able to get whether it's a `List<String>` because of the [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

If you simply want to check whether it's a `List` or not then you can do,

```
return method.getReturnType().contains("java.util.List");
```

Comment: @Cilenco What's the problem in just `return method.getReturnType().contains("List");`?

Comment: This would not work if you create an own class named List

Answer (score -1):

This was my solution to this problem(Very simple):

```
 public static boolean isParameterizedType(Class clazz) {
        String simpleName = clazz.getSimpleName();
        return parameterizedTypeSet.contains(simpleName);
    }

private static Set<String> parameterizedTypeSet = new HashSet<>();

    static {
        parameterizedTypeSet.add("List");
    }
```

Comment: This code has no mention of `ClassName` and thus cannot possibly answer the question.  Determining whether it is parameterized is also not the same as determining whether it is a `List`.